# Gnuplot workflow involving loops of fits that get multiplotted

Tags: loops, gnuplot

I want to do the following in gnuplot:
read my files, which are conveniently labeled "filenameN.txt", where N is the Nth file.

Fit some polynom fN(x)to the data, using aN, bN,...
and plot all of those in a single graphic (multiple plots) using multiplot

However, I cannot get this to work using the loops available in gnuplot.
What does work is for example creating one file, that does what I want for N, and then running an external loop that passes N=1...M.

This results in M plots, but not in a single multiplot.

For this to work I need to assign variables with variable names (f1, f2, ... a1, a2, ..., ...) for the fits (since I potentially want to use all of them together somehow)

I also want the plot loop to produce simple plots in a multiplot (each containing data and its fit, M times, not a multiplot where the first plot contains all of the lines, and the rest of the plots are empty.

So I have two questions then:

- How to assign variable variable-names
- How to use loops in a multiplot layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define you function depending on N like:

```
fstr(N) = sprintf('f%d(x) = a%d*x**2 + b%d*x + c%d', N, N, N, N)
eval(fstr(1))
```

This defines the function `f1(x) = a1*x**2 + b1*x + c1`. For the fitting function you must do the same:

```
fitstr(N) = sprintf('fit ''filename%d.txt'' f%d(x) via a%d,b%d,c%d', N, N, N, N, N)
```

Then you first do all the fits:

```
do for [i=0:N] {
    eval(fstr(i))
    eval(fitstr(i))
}
```

and then plot each data file `with points` and the corresponding fit `with lines`. In order to have all plots in one graph, you must use a single `plot` command and separate the plots with a comma.

But in order to group fit and data in the key you can use `replot` to add plots. And you must use `macros` to get the correct function in the plots, `eval` doesn't work here:

```
set style data points
set style func lines
plot 'filename0.txt' lt 1, f0(x) lt 1
set macros
do for [i=1:N] {
    f = sprintf('f%d(x)', i)
    replot sprintf('filename%d.txt', i) lt (i+1), @f lt (i+1)
}
```

Just put everything together in one file and run gnuplot with it.