# Fitting and plotting a series in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167590/fitting-function-with-multiple-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384477/how-to-fit-a-function-with-multiple-files-in-gnuplot) but my problem is that I have several hundred files that need to be simultaneously fitted and plotted on one graph. Unlike the other questions posted I'm looking for the best fits for each file, not for the global data set so `cat` won't work.

I was hoping to use `fit.. for` like I do for `plot` but it's not working so well. Here's what I've got so far:

```
f(x) = 1+d*exp(-(x-f)**2/(2*(g**2)))+a*exp((-(x-b)**2)/(2*(c**2)))

filename(n) = sprintf("rheosaxs_saxs_%005d_0001_var_rebin_div.dat", n)
fit f(x) for [n=575:584] filename(n) u 1:2 via a,b,c,d,f,g
plot for [n=575:584] filename(n) using 1:2, f(x)
```

the error I get is: `line 60: undefined variable: for`
which corresponds to the `fit f(x) for [n=a:b]`

I know that my starting parameters are reasonable because I can plot them without the fit command and they look sensible. Similarly my `plot for` works ok.

Any ideas? Thank you :)

Comment: If your `fit ... for` would work, you would always overwrite the estimated fit parameters of the previous iteration. I posted a possible solution for such a szenario in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20323981/2604213, not sure if now there is a better approach using array, which were introduced with version 5.2.

Comment: I don't think that will work because `for` is defined differently in gnuplot to the standard definition

Comment: What do you refer to, that doesn't work? The answer  I linked to, works as such. With arrays I mean something like `do for [i = 1:10] { fit ... via a; array[i] = a; }` I'll see later at home, if that could work.

Comment: ah ok, I think I understand :) I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 5.2 gnuplot introduces arrays, which allow you to save the results of each fit and plot those later.

A simplified example script would be

```
file(n) = sprintf('myfile_%d.dat', n)
f(a, x) = a*x

array A[10]
do for [i=1:10] {
    tmpA = 1
    fit f(tmpA, x) file(i) via tmpA
    A[i] = tmpA
}

plot for [i=1:10] file(i),\
     for [i=1:10] f(A[i], x)
```

Although gnuplots arrays are implemented as linked list of user variables, it is not possible to use `A[i]` directly for the fit, but I had to use a temporary variable to get it right.

A full working example, including generation of random data, with python from gnuplot, uargh ;):

```
# generate some random data
system("python3 -c 'import random\nfor i in range(1, 11):\n\twith open(\"output_{0}.dat\".format(i), \"w\") as f:\n\t\tf.write(chr(10).join([str(i*100 + i* x * (1 + 0.1*(random.random()-0.5))) for x in range(0,100)]))'")


file(n) = sprintf('output_%d.dat', n)

f(a, b, x) = a*x + b
array A[10]
array B[10]
do for [i=1:10] {
    tmpA = 1
    tmpB = 1
    fit f(tmpA, tmpB, x) file(i) u 0:1 via tmpA, tmpB
    A[i] = tmpA
    B[i] = tmpB
}

plot for [i = 1:10] file(i) u 0:1 with points lt i notitle, \
     for [i=1:10] f(A[i], B[i], x) with lines lt i notitle
```

[image]

BTW: There is no `fit for`, because that is equivalent to `do for { fit }`. But when plotting, `plot for` generates a single plot with multiple functions, whereas `do for { plot }` makes several plots and should be used with `multiplot`