# Draw fit functions for multiple cases

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I have a data file in which two cases are separated with headers such as `ncell=...`. I draw these data points with

```
plot for [IDX=0:1] "file.dat" i IDX u 1:2 w lines title columnheader(1)
```

I would like to fit these data points into functions (does not matter which for now), get the parameters for each case and draw fit functions  instead of actual data points. I am aware of [fit function](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node82.html) but I don't know how to use it when data file contains multiple cases.

**file.dat**:

```
ncell=1000000
8 46.42716
12 27.6141
16 23.77418
20 20.81404
24 21.55132
28 22.70293
32 19.75053


ncell=3000000
8 188.0772
12 101.4686
16 72.4076
20 76.0597
24 61.2208
28 61.44395
32 62.1787
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959036/2604213

Comment: But I have only single file not array of files.

Comment: That should give you the idea of how to use arrays for saving the fit parameters, which is the main problem. Whether you iterate over files or indices  in a single file doesn't really matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fitting and plotting a series in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929262/fitting-and-plotting-a-series-in-gnuplot)